# Embed PDF in WebPage in Grails

Tags: html, pdf, grails, embed

How can I embed an external PDF file, when i say external I mean that the pdf has a relative path which is found in another folder on the server, and not in the root application.

Right now when I use object

```
<object class="print_this" id="report" name="report" type="application/pdf" data="Certificate.pdf"></object>
```

The server tells me that the file does not exist>

Comment: Give full path for example: http://locahost/path

Comment: I am giving /data/certificates for example and it does not take it into account: GET https://localhost:8443/data/certificates/Certificate.pdf 404 (Not Found)